# How to know collection view's `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` method call has finished?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, completionhandler

I have a viewController with a `UICollectionView`, to which I'm setting headers I need their height to be calculated dynamically. My implementation of the `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` is similar to this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
    customHeader.layoutIfNeeded()
    let height = customHeader.container.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

I'd need to know when this call has been completed and the size of the headers have been set, in order to trigger some other actions I need to perform.

I've seen that both `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` methods of the viewController are called before this other one. Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Comment: did you find the answer to this question?